# When do you top up steering fluid on a 1997 BMW 318ti Coupe?

Tags: power-steering, fluid-level, 318ti

I have a 1997 BMW 318ti.

I'm concerned my power steering fluid is low and am curious about when I would want to top it off.

- Is there a certain amount of mileage where I should check it?
- Do I check it after it has cooled or when it's hot?
- How do I know when to top it off?
- Is the measuring stick underneath the fluid cap the correct way to measure it?

Answer (score 1):

The cap of the power steering fluid bottle has a built in dip-stick which shows minimum and maximum levels.  If the fluid is below the minimum mark of this dip-stick, it's time to add fluid.